# QLineEdit::text() returns non-string

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm having a strange problem getting the text value of a QLineEdit.

On a QWidget there is a QLineEdit and a QDialogButtonBox. When the Ok button is clicked, the value of the QLineEdit shall be read and saved.

Here's my code:

properties.h

```
#ifndef PROPERTIES_H
#define PROPERTIES_H
#include "config.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>

namespace Ui {
          class properties;
}

class properties : public QDialog {
      Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit properties(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~properties();

    private slots:
        void on_buttonBox_accepted();

    private:
        Ui::properties *pProp;

};

#endif // PROPERTIES_H
```

properties.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "properties.h"
#include "Form.h"
#include "ui_properties.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QFileDialog>

properties::properties(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent),
                                          pProp(new Ui::properties) {
    pProp->setupUi(this);
    pProp->NameEdit->setText(QString("test"));
}

properties::~properties() { delete pProp; }

void properties::on_buttonBox_accepted()     {
     QString qstr = pProp->NameEdit->text();
     std::string stdstr = qstr.toStdString();
     const char *cstr = stdstr.c_str();

     qDebug() << "qDebug: " << pProp->NameEdit->text();
     std::cout << "cout stdstr: " << stdstr;

     this->close();
}
```

The output is

```
qDebug:  "test"
cout stdstr:
```

and it crashed with a "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'stdstr' was corrupted." when leaving the method.

The content of stdstr is something like "à<(¸¶\x1" when I inspect it using VisualStudio debugger.
This works with Qt version 5.14, however using version 5.12 it does not.

What am I missing?

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: How are you checking the value of `stdstr`?

Comment: Using the VisualStudio debugger.

Comment: What was the real content of the line edit?

Comment: Since i do not necessarily enter anything into the LineEdit, it should be "test", as set in the constructor. I see the content "test" in the window, so at least setting the value is working.

Comment: Tried to rebuild your project? What is the output of `qDebug () << pProp->NameEdit->text()`?

Comment: Interesting.

qDebug:  "test"
cout stdstr:

I added this output to the question.

Comment: Have you tried to recompile your program? Do you compile your program with the same version of Visual Studio as Qt is compiled with? Or you mixing debug and release libraries?

Comment: _QLineEdit::text() returns non-string_ From what you have posted, I do not see any evidance supporting this claim.